# unable to use firebase and location plugins through flutter and android

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dex

I've been working on this issue for 2 whole days now and am no closer to solving this.

I am using flutter, and after doing the codelabs tutorial for firebase, I tried adding location into the mix. My dependencies in pubspec.yaml, build.gradle, and app/build.gradle look like this.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
#  image_picker: 0.1.1                                             # new
#  google_sign_in: 0.3.1                                           # new
#  firebase_analytics: 0.0.4                                       # new
#  firebase_auth: 0.2.0                                            # new
  firebase_database: 0.0.12                                       # old
  firebase_storage: 0.0.5                                         # old
#  firebase_database: 0.4.6                                       # new
#  firebase_storage: 0.3.3                                         # new
  location: "^1.2.0"
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.takaoandrew.flutteralight"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error I get doing this is

Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (11.0.4) and runtime (11.8.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I have tried manually overriding my play-services, but I don't know how to do this with flutter. Back when it was all android, I chose the version number myself. Uncommenting the following lines from app/build.gradle

```
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
//    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1") {
//        force = true;
//    }
```

gives me the error

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

-- this is a classic error for me. Uncommenting the line

//        multiDexEnabled true

in app/build.gradle doesn't change with the unable to merge dex error.

The dependencies seem to be a mess to me, so I tried looking at a dependency tree. I want to see my gradle dependencies to try and align everything. When I run ./gradlew :app/dependencies I get

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.

Whether somebody knows what my issues are, or someone has helpful references to help me understand gradle dependencies, and how they relate to flutter dependencies, or how to resolve problems with 'dex', or any tips at all... I would greatly appreciate it because I am banging my head against the wall right now. I have tried other solutions I've seen in StackOverflow and nothing has worked. And the iOS version runs fine so far.